# How to write a recursive algorithm with axis?

Tags: java, recursion, axis, point, binary-search

I need to find an object on a x and y axis coordinates recursively. In this particular code I need to find "Remy" who is in the coordinate 168,250 by calling the search method repeatedly

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class Sensor {

private Point target;
private Point[] points = {new Point(378, 349), new Point(147, 315), new Point(95, 375), new Point(242, 493), new Point(379, 389), new Point(168, 250), new Point(130, 220), new Point(160, 200), new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 511), new Point(511, 0), new Point(511, 511)};
private String[] names = {"Bernstein", "DukeDog", "Huey", "Hedwig", "Flipper", "Remy", "QuadCat", "Nemo", "UL", "LL", "UR", "LR"};

public Sensor(String paramString) {
    this.target = new Point(512, 512);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.names.length; i++) {
        if (paramString.equalsIgnoreCase(this.names[i])) {
            this.target = this.points[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sensor sensor = new Sensor("Remy");
    Point result = sensor.search(0, 0, 512);
    if (result != null) {
        System.out.println("location: " + result.x + "," + result.y);
    } else {
        System.out.println("unable to find");
    }
}

public Point search(int x, int y, int width) {
    //Write a recursive algorithm to find Remy calling the scan method repeatedly such as: scan(x,y,width); 
    //todo 
    return null;
}

public int scan(int paramInt1, int paramInt2, int paramInt3) {
    if ((this.target.x >= paramInt1) && (this.target.x < paramInt1 + paramInt3) && (this.target.y >= paramInt2) && (this.target.y < paramInt2 + paramInt3)) {
        return paramInt3;
    } else {
        return -paramInt3;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

```
public Point search(int x, int y, int width) {

    System.out.println(x + "\t" + y + "\t" + width);

    int w = width/2;
    if(w<=1)
        return new Point(x,y); 
    int x1 = x+w;
    int y1 = y+w; 

    if(target.x>=x&&target.x<x1&&target.y>=y&&target.y<y1)
        return search(x,y,w); 
    else if(target.x>=x1&&target.x<x+w&&target.y>=y&&target.y<y1)
        return search(x1,y,w); 
    else if(target.x>=x&&target.x<x1&&target.y>=y1&&target.y<y1+w)
        return search(x,y1,w); 
    else /*if(target.x>=x1&&target.x<=x+w&&target.y>=y1&&target.y<=y1+w)*/
        return search(x1,y1,w); 
}
```

When you run this method, the output is:

```
0   0   512
0   0   256
128 128 128
128 192 64
160 224 32
160 240 16
168 248 8
168 248 4
168 250 2
location: 168,250
```

Note that it assumes that `width` is a power of 2. This can easily be adapted.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Does it answer your question?